# Background position won't position itself

Tags: html, css

I have my site wrapped in one big DIV, called wrapper, that starts just after `<body>` and ends right before it. I.e.

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    ... website ...
  </div>
</body>
```

I have the following code styling *#wrapper*

```
#wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 7px;
 background: #c1cca0 url(images/fade.gif) repeat-y scroll 0 300px;
}
```

However, the background starts repeating at the very top of the page, instead of 300 pixels down. Can I not use `repeat-y` in conjunction with `background-position`, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Please use http://doctype.com/

Comment: Did you try other values than 300px? Maybe it just appears that the image begins right at the top of the element. But if your image is about 300 pixels high, it just might be shifted by one repetition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but could you try to define the background-position using it's own property, like:

```
background-position: 0px 300px;
```

Please tell, if this will fix it.

Comment: I think this is it, or the fact that you are using `0` instead of `0px`.

Comment: 0 is a perfectly valid value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried

    #wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 7px;
 background: #c1cca0 url(images/fade.gif) repeat-y scroll;
 background-position: 0 700px;
}

but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I not use repeat-y in conjunction with background-position,

Yes you are right .. There is no meaning to the combination of repeat-y and absolution position .. repeat-y overrides ..
I don't know what fade.gif exactly is (as it is only literal in your code) .. so can't try for the alternative solution ..

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here but I think the source of your problem is that the #wrapper has no height of its own. Try giving it a fixed height to test this out.... i.e. #wrapper {height: 500px;}